# Discord.py - 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Tags: python, discord.py

everyone. I'm writing a Discord bot, for play sound. but I'm faced with a problem.

```
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel
```

Could anyone here help me please? Thank you for any comments.

Function:

```
import asyncio
import discord, time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def bb(ctx):
    user = ctx.message.author
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
    player = voice.create_ffmpeg_player('1.m4a')
    player.start()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the rewrite version, version 1.0, `VoiceState.voice_channel` was changed to [`VoiceState.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel).

If you are using the rewrite version, the below should be sufficient to play a file:

```
from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
async def bb(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    if not channel:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    voice = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
    source = FFmpegPCMAudio('1.m4a')
    player = voice.play(source)
```

Comment: you are perfect answer! i've question, how to solve error: Already connected to a voice channel. i tried any possibility, but i don't know.

Comment: @Kaya I added some code to check for an existing connection and switch channels if necessary.  Can you try it out and let me know?